# Using Doxygen for Visual Studio 2008 project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, documentation, doxygen

I want to install and create Doxygen HTML documentation for one of the projects in my solution. Could you please tell the process step by step. I have Googled and found nowhere such information.

EDIT:
Could it be integrated to Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have downloaded doxygen doxygen-1.8.2-setup.exe from http://www.doxygen.nl/download.html and installed it. Then run it, gave the directory of the project I need documentation for and some other options. And that is it!

Answer (score 3):

Did you try the Doxygen documentation? :) 
http://www.doxygen.nl/manual

What I would do is go through the installation project and make some boilerplate examples that just outline the methods you are creating. Start small.

EDIT: Just saw your post about using with VS 2008. While I have not tried Doxygen with that particular version, I would suspect that it should be possible as you are just marking up your comments with tags that Doxygen recognizes

Answer (score 0):

You first need to ensure doxygen is installed and accessible on the system path. You may also want to install graphviz (dot) for graph drawing.

Next, run:

```
doxygen -g MyProject.doxyconf
```

This generates a doxygen configuration file. Edit this file to customize it. It contains comments describing what the options do, so set those accordingly.

You can now generate doxygen documentation using:

```
doxygen MyProject.doxyconf
```

To integrate this with Visual Studio, create a new makefile project (e.g. MyProject.documentation). This can then be configured to run the following commands:

```
Build   : doxygen MyProject.doxyconf
ReBuild : doxygen MyProject.doxyconf
Clean   : cd $(ProjectDir)/docs && del /s *.*
```

NOTE: I am not sure if `$(ProjectDir)` is correct, but you still need to change `$(ProjectDir)/docs` to the location where the documentation is generated.

You can then add documentation to the project as needed. My advice on this is to do it iteratively. Start in one area (header/class) and look at what output doxygen produces, then incrementally refine it.

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html shows the basics of adding doxygen documentation.

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html provides a reference of all available commands usable within doxygen comments.

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual provides additional documentation.